# If statement won't work in Inform 7

Tags: inform7

```
The toggle is a device.
The toggle is switched on.
If the toggle is switched on:
    say "Hi there.".
```

The third line shows an error about punctuation, saying the phrase doesn't make sense. How is the punctuation wrong, it seems completely fine?

Answer (score 4):

The error message is a bit misleading, but the core issue is that you need context for the if phrase. In other words, you need to define *when* the condition should be checked, otherwise it's too vague.

It's not entirely clear what you want the code to do, but you could have for example:

```
Every turn:
    if the toggle is switched on:
        say "Hi there."
```